# Selenium RC doesnt work in IE but works fine in other browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

My Stack Trace:

```
 [java] 23 May 11 15:21:08, ERROR Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
 [java] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource not found: /core
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.ResourceExtractor.extractResourcePath(ResourceExtractor.java:39)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.HTABrowserLauncher.createHTAFiles(HTABrowserLauncher.java:88)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.HTABrowserLauncher.launch(HTABrowserLauncher.java:63)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.HTABrowserLauncher.launchRemoteSession(HTABrowserLauncher.java:166)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.InternetExplorerLauncher.launchRemoteSession(InternetExplorerLauncher.java:77)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.createNewRemoteSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:372)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:124)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession(BrowserSessionFactory.java:86)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.getNewBrowserSession(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:733)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCommand(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:399)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleCommandRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:370)
 [java]     at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:129)
 [java]     at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
 [java]     at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
 [java]     at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
 [java]     at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
 [java]     at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
 [java]     at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
 [java]     at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:245)
 [java]     at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
 [java]     at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
 [java] 23 May 11 15:21:08, INFO  Got result: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser on session null
```

This error occurs only when i run selenium test cases from a java class as below:

public static void main(String[] args) {
    org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main("com.selenium.test.TestSelenium");
  }

This error is not occured when selenium is run from Ant script as below

Comment: Which IE version?  6, 7, 8, or 9?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you are not using Selenium v2.0's WebDriver instead? It will resolve browser location and dependencies automatically and no need to start the RC manually. It requires a rewrite of the tests, but well worth it!

Answer (score 0):

Use setBrowser("*iexploreproxy");

and Try the same also it can remove the javascript error many times people face while executing with *iehta.

While executing with the above browser mode you should be running from administrator login.